# Sublime Text 3 Japanese character not in base line with others

Tags: sublimetext3

As you see in picture below, 2 characters is lower than the following word. I try to change font or reinstall Sublime but it doesn't work.

This is the text :

```
新規Add
```

It doesn't happen with gedit on Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: can you share the text also as characters (not only as picture) so people can copy into their sublime and reproduce your issue?

Comment: @snoram I had edit my question

Comment: I get the same look as you on Sublime 3.1.1. and Windows 10. Maybe you should contact Sublime directly?

Comment: What fonts are you using?

Comment: @jwpfox I use the default font of Sublime. I also tried changing `font_face` too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: That is not an answer that allows anyone to help you. Name the fonts you are having trouble with.